# Showing and hiding google visualization chart on page load.

Tags: charts, google-visualization, line

I have two google line charts. I have made code for them in single function and call it on `google.setOnLoadCallback()` event. But at first time when page loads I want to show only one chart and other chart should call on clicking button. Also on clicking the button I have shown and hidden charts on their names but I want to show only one chart at the first time. I have also tried to show first chart but when I click for other chart then it gets spread in width and demolish the UI. So any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should initially draw with both chart containers visible, as drawing inside a hidden div breaks the Visualization API's internal dimension detection algorithms (which is why your chart draws incorrectly when hidden).  Use a "ready" event handler to hide the chart when it is finished drawing:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(hiddenChart, 'ready', function () {
    document.querySelector('#hiddenChartDiv').style.display = 'none';
});
```

Place the event handler after creating the chart but before drawing it.